# sorting nested cell as one arrange function

Tags: matlab

i have a mat data and extract 8 feature this file.
i should arrange this features as a cell and repeat that for 12 category
i want to arrange and uniform this code as one code?

```
feature_mean1=zeros(12,15);
 for vmean1= 1:12
 feature_mean1(vmean1,:)= mean(Catrgoryy1{vmean1});
 end
feature_mean2=zeros(12,15);
 for vmean2= 1:12
 feature_mean2(vmean2,:)= mean(Catrgoryy2{vmean2});
end
%**********************
 %***************
feature_min1=zeros(12,15);
for vmin1= 1:12
feature_min1(vmin1,:)= min(Catrgoryy1{vmin1});
end
feature_min2=zeros(12,15);
for vmin2= 1:12
feature_min2(vmin2,:)= min(Catrgoryy2{vmin2});
end
  %***************
 X=zeros(30,4); 

h=1;
X_1=[feature_mean1(1,:)',feature_std1(1,:)',feature_min1(1,:)',feature_max1(1,:)',feature_mean2(1,:)',feature_std2(1,:)',feature_min2(1,:)',feature_max2(1,:)'];%
Y_1=repmat(1,length(X_1),1);
%%%**************222*************                                       
X_2=[feature_mean1(2,:)',feature_std1(2,:)',feature_min1(2,:)',feature_max1(2,:)',feature_mean2(2,:)',feature_std2(2,:)',feature_min2(2,:)',feature_max2(2,:)'];
Y_2=repmat(2,length(X_2),1);
%%%**************333**************
.
.
.
X_12=[feature_mean1(12,:)',feature_std1(12,:)',feature_min1(12,:)',feature_max1(12,:)',feature_mean2(12,:)',feature_std2(12,:)',feature_min2(12,:)',feature_max2(12,:)'];
Y_12=repmat(12,length(X_12),1);
```

Comment: Where is your problem implementing this? Just put it into a for loop like you did in the upper part of the code.

Comment: i make 8 array for this feature but i cant save it at individual cell

Comment: for o=1:12
  Xf(o,:)=[feature_mean11{o},feature_std11{o},feature_min11{o},feature_max11{o},feature_mean22{o},feature_std22{o},feature_min22{o},feature_max22{o}];
end

Comment: i recieve this error: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: can you correct this code to uniform for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first must be form 8 array for each of the Features
then insert all of them in the for loop

```
for o=1:12
  Xf(o,:)=[feature_mean11{o},feature_std11{o},feature_min11{o},feature_max11{o},feature_mean22{o},feature_std22{o},feature_min22{o},feature_max22{o}];
end
```

finish